# Pass Asterisk(*) as ant property value lost between shell/batch

Tags: shell, batch-file, asterisk

I have a following command to build ProjectA;

```
build.bat release -Dinclude.dir="X/Source/Private/ProjectA/ivy.xml"
```

Where build.bat internally calls 'ant release -Dinclude.dir="X/Source/Private/ProjectA/ivy.xml"' and its WORKS OK.

Now as soon as I update above into following to pick all IVY projects from X directory it stops working and ANT throws error;

```
build.bat release -Dinclude.dir="X/**/ivy.xml"

Missing value for property include.dir
```

I debugged a little in batch script and it seems my batch is calling ant as follows if I apply error command;

```
ant release -Dinclude.dir=
```

Somehow batch/shell (same things happens if run on Linux with build.sh) are not able to interpret the value which contains '*' in them?

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Can you post your batch script so that we can see how the parameter is being handled?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. The newest part is at top.. I think covered the scenarios you may be looking for..

Answer (score 0):

Here you go..

```
echo ^*^*
pause
```

and yields..

```
**
Press any key to continue
```

Change your line to be:

```
build.bat release -Dinclude.dir="X/^*^*/ivy.xml"
```

I think you maybe asking for the following ...

[Pass, escape and recognize Special Character in Windows Batch File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545788/pass-escape-and-recognize-special-character-in-windows-batch-file)

If not...

I think you are running into a little known issue with Windows (DOS) wildcards..

Where you have:

```
build.bat release -Dinclude.dir="X/**/ivy.xml"
```

I think you need to replace with:

```
build.bat release -Dinclude.dir="X/??/ivy.xml"
```

With the ?? it is only two exact placeholders with wildcards. The asterisk is more all-encompassing.  If you have more like a date, year, you need to do something like: ????-??-??  where it would represent: 2015-03-09 as an example...
Hope this helps!